# Solving $\tan\frac3{9.8m}\tan\frac4{9.8m}=1$ for $m$

Tags: trigonometry

While solving a physics problem, I got stuck at
this equation:
$$
\tan\left(3 \over 9.8\, m\right)\tan\left(4 \over 9.8\, m\right) = 1
$$
I am seeking $m$. I know some trigonometry but not much to solve it,  I shall be highly obliged to have an answer.

Comment: If $(\tan a)(\tan b)=1$, then $\tan a=\cot b=\tan((\pi/2)-b)$, so it's worth checking to see whether $a=(\pi/2)-b$ gets you anywhere.

Comment: I tried it,but it worth nothing.The question i m asking comes from those steps which you are suggesting me to follow.

Comment: Taking $k=\frac1{9.8m}$ you have $3k=\frac\pi2-4k$ or $k=\frac\pi{14}$. The other solutions are multiples.

Comment: If you have prior work for this problem (as your comment indicates) you should edit the question to include it. I'm rather dubious that what you have is a valid result: I could understand $\tan^{-1}(F/mg)$ appearing in a physics problem, but _not_ $\tan(F/mg)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Is that method correct for all values that the $\tan$ function can take in?

Comment: @Curious, I don't know. Did you try it, to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***HINT***

$$\tan\frac3{9.8m}\tan\frac4{9.8m}=1$$

Here you consider $\frac{1}{9.8m}$ to be $a$. The equation then becomes $$\tan3a\tan4a=1.$$

The formula for $\tan (a + b)$ is $$\frac{\tan A + \tan B}{1 - \tan A \tan B}$$

From where you can find $\tan 3a$ and $\tan4a$. Then find out the value of $a$ and solve for $m$.

***PS***

This might be a lengthy process but if you just need the value of $m$. [Here it is](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%7B3%2F(9.8a)%7D+tan%7B4%2F(9.8a)%7D%3D1).

Answer (score 1):

Following the hint in superb jhon's answer we put ${1\over 9.8 m}=:\alpha$, and then have to solve the equation
$$\tan(3\alpha)\tan(4\alpha)=1\ .\tag{1}$$
Here the left hand side is even and $\pi$-periodic in $\alpha$. It is therefore sufficient to find the solutions in the interval $\bigl[0,{\pi\over2}\bigr]$. Values $\alpha$ where $\tan(3\alpha)$ or $\tan(4\alpha)$ is undefined fall out of the question. We therefore may replace $(1)$ by
$$2\sin(3\alpha)\sin(4\alpha)=2\cos(3\alpha)\cos(4\alpha)\ ,$$
or
$$\cos\alpha-\cos(7\alpha)=\cos\alpha+\cos(7\alpha)\ ,$$
and this is equivalent with $\cos(7\alpha)=0$. It follows that $7\alpha$ is an odd multiple of ${\pi\over2}$, and together with the condition $0\leq\alpha<{\pi\over2}$ we obtain
$$\alpha\in\left\{{\pi\over14},\ {3\pi\over14},\ {5\pi\over14}\right\}\tag{2}$$
as a necessary condition. A quick check (no numerics required) reveals that all three found candidates indeed solve $(1)$. The totality of solutions of $(1)$ is then obtained by symmetrizing the set $(2)$ with respect to $0$ and repeating the resulting pattern periodically with period $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

A very *ad hoc* solution is to observe that complementary angles (angles that sum up to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians, or $90$ degrees) have tangents that are reciprocals of one another.  Thus, if we confine ourselves to angles between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$, we have

$$
\frac{3}{9.8m}+\frac{4}{9.8m} = \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

or

$$
\frac{7}{9.8m} = \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

which yields $m = \frac{10}{7\pi}$.